# Honda Stereo Not Working - How to Troubleshoot?

Tags: electrical, honda

I have a Honda Odyssey 2004 V6 with the optional DVD package.  Recently, the stereo went out and won't turn on.  We thought it may be the fuse at first, but the fuse says "INTR LIGHTS STEREO" and the interior lights work fine.  So we think the stereo died, but is there a way to troubleshoot these types of problems?

Also, I bring up the DVD package because the DVD player screen died years back, but the DVD player also died at the same time...  in the Honda, the DVD player is right below the stereo.

What should I look to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some stereos (although usually not OE ones) have fuses built in to the back of them. You'd have to remove it to see if it does and if it's blown. Otherwise, it may just be dead.

Typically OE stereos, and to an even greater extend OE video systems, are not worth the cost to replace unless you can find a used one. Aftermarket stereos and video systems can bring your more features for less.

From the way the other devices died at about the same time--it almost sounds like planned obsolescence!

Comment: Turns out it was a fuse for the stereo, but the player had a defect.  Thanks.